# help removing mysql file sort

Tags: sql, optimization, mysql

Here is the log output:

```
# Time: 100915 13:06:49
# User@Host: ss[ss] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 13.978355  Lock_time: 0.000029 Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 562760
use ss;
SET timestamp=1284574009;

  SELECT DISTINCT 
         SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
         B.*, 
         U.username 
    FROM sc_users AS U, 
         sc_bookmarks AS B     
   WHERE B.uId = U.uId 
     AND B.bStatus = 0 
GROUP BY B.bHash 
ORDER BY B.bModified DESC
   LIMIT 10;
```

and the explain output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   SIMPLE  U   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    2   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  B   ALL sc_bookmarks_usd    NULL    NULL    NULL    187586  Using where; Using join buffer
```

UPDATE: Here is the create statement for sc_users thanks OMGPonies / BrianHooper :-)

```
CREATE TABLE `sc_users` (
  `uId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `uDatetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `uModified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `homepage` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uContent` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uId`)
)     ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

More details (thanks  Mark Byers):

This query is generated by the open source project semanticscuttle to generate the home-page.  I do not know why the query was written as it was, as I am just getting my feet wet in this project.  [You can see the source where this sql is generated here though.](http://semanticscuttle.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/semanticscuttle/trunk/src/SemanticScuttle/Service/Bookmark.php?revision=693&view=markup)

I have tried adding various indexes and combined indexes with no luck speeding up the query or removing the file scan.  Any tips are appreciated!

UPDATE: The slow-down is caused by the ORDER BY statement...
The query bellow runs in 4 seconds with the ORDER BY, 0.01 seconds without it.
Any ideas why / how to fix it?

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS B.*, U.username 
FROM sc_users AS U, sc_bookmarks AS B 
WHERE B.uId = U.uId 
AND B.bStatus = 0 
GROUP BY B.bHash 
ORDER BY B.bModified DESC
```

UPDATE: NEW SQL and index Quassnoi in an answer bellow... This looked great to me, but actually increased execution time, and didn't get rid of the file sorts:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_CACHE b.*, u.username  FROM    (         SELECT  DISTINCT bHash         FROM    sc_bookmarks b         WHERE   bStatus = 0         ) bd JOIN    sc_bookmarks b ON      b.bId =         (         SELECT  bId         FROM    sc_bookmarks bi         WHERE   bi.bStatus = 0                 AND bi.bHash = bd.bHash         ORDER BY                 bStatus DESC, bHash DESC, bModified DESC, bId DESC         LIMIT 1         ) JOIN    sc_users u ON      u.uId = b.uId ORDER BY         bModified ASC LIMIT 10;
+----+--------------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+------------------+---------+----------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | type   | possible_keys            | key              | key_len | ref      | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+--------------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+------------------+---------+----------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                     | NULL             | NULL    | NULL     | 187565 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | b          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,sc_bookmarks_usd | PRIMARY          | 4       | func     |      1 | Using where                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | u          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,su_idx           | PRIMARY          | 4       | ss.b.uId |      1 |                                 |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | bi         | ref    | sc_bookmarks_hui,bStatus | sc_bookmarks_hui | 98      | bd.bHash |      1 | Using where; Using filesort     |
|  2 | DERIVED            | b          | ref    | bStatus                  | bStatus          | 1       |          |  94556 | Using where; Using index        |
+----+--------------------+------------+--------+--------------------------+------------------+---------+----------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

UPDATE: per the request of Quassnoi, here is the CREATE TABLE statement for sc_bookmarks.

```
CREATE TABLE `sc_bookmarks` (
 `bId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `uId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `bIp` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bStatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `bDatetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `bModified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `bTitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `bAddress` varchar(1500) NOT NULL,
 `bDescription` text,
 `bPrivateNote` text,
 `bHash` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `bVotes` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `bVoting` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `bShort` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`bId`),
 KEY `sc_bookmarks_usd` (`uId`,`bStatus`,`bDatetime`),
 KEY `sc_bookmarks_hui` (`bHash`,`uId`,`bId`),
 KEY `sc_bookmarks_du` (`bDatetime`,`uId`),
 KEY `sc_bookmarks_modified_idx` (`bModified`),
 KEY `bStatus` (`bStatus`,`bHash`,`bModified`,`uId`,`bId`),
 KEY `bHash` (`bHash`),
 CONSTRAINT `sc_bookmarks_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`uId`) REFERENCES `sc_users` (`uId`),
 CONSTRAINT `sc_bookmarks_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`uId`) REFERENCES `sc_users` (`uId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=187566 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

UPDATE with jacobs feedback on cwiske's answer.
The query is well optimized, but it does not return the same results as the original query.

For example I have 3 entries in table "sc_bookmarks".

```
bId           bModified      bHash
------------------------------------
2000-11-10    aaaaaa         ...
2011-12-12    bbbbbb         ...
2010-11-11    aaaaaa         ...
```

The query should return only row id 1 and 2. But it return all 3 records. Seems mysql doesn't like: ´GROUP BY B.bModified DESC, B.bHash DESC´

I tried to change ´GROUP BY B.bModified DESC, B.bHash DESC´

to ´GROUP BY B.bModified, B.bHash
GROUP BY B.bHash, B.bModified´

but I'm still getting all 3 records.

It works when I leave ´GROUP BY B.bHash´ but that prevents the index from working.

Comment: The filesort is on the `sc_users` table - please post the CREATE TABLE statement for it.

Comment: What is the purpose of the DISTINCT when you have a GROUP BY? Doesn't the GROUP BY already guarantee that the values of B.bHash in the result set will be distinct? And are you aware that including columns in the result that aren't in the group by can lead to indeterminate results in some situations? Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Er...it looks like you posted the code for the wrong table...

Comment: @Eric: could you please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE sc_bookmarks`?

Comment: Of course... It's now been added above, and I appreciate the help!

Comment: I should mention that I converted the tables to InnoDB to support Foreign Keys... Really sorry if that's what threw of your SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try Your query cweiske.

This works great, no "Using temporary" or "Using filesort"

But it return wrong records.

For example I have 3 entries in table "sc_bookmarks".

bId, bModified, bHash, ...

1, 2000-11-10, aaaaaa, ...

2, 2011-12-12, bbbbbb, ...

3, 2010-11-11, aaaaaa, ...

So I expect that Your query return only row id 1 and 2. But it return all 3 records. Looks like mysql don't like "GROUP BY B.bModified DESC, B.bHash DESC"

I try to change "GROUP BY B.bModified DESC, B.bHash DESC" to

- GROUP BY B.bModified, B.bHash
- GROUP BY B.bHash, B.bModified

but it newer works ok, still getting 3 records.

It works only when I leave "GROUP BY B.bHash" but in this case index is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It might not hurt to run [ANALYZE TABLE first](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html):

```
ANALYZE TABLE sc_users;
ANALYZE TABLE sc_bookmarks;
```

Let's see if there's improvement if you [add the following index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html):

```
CREATE INDEX su_idx USING BTREE ON SC_USERS(uid, username)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I added the index, and ran analyze tables, Unfortunately it did not change the run time, or the result of the explain statement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to retrieve last modified bookmark for each hash and the user associated with it.

Assuming that the `PRIMARY KEY` column on `sc_bookmarks` is called `id`:

```
SELECT  b.*, u.username 
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT bHash
        FROM    sc_bookmarks b
        WHERE   bStatus = 0
        ) bd
JOIN    sc_bookmarks b
ON      b.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    sc_bookmarks bi
        WHERE   bi.bStatus = 0
                AND bi.bHash = bd.bHash
        ORDER BY
                bStatus DESC, bHash DESC, bModified DESC, id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
JOIN    sc_users u
ON      u.uId = b.uId
ORDER BY
        bModified DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Create an index on `sc_bookmarks (bStatus, bHash bModified, id)` for this to work fast.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I posted the result of the new explain above.  Unfortunately  it's still executing 2 file sorts, and is taking a bit longer (I did also create the suggested index)

Answer (score 1):

To get optimal performance, the query needs to be as follows:

```
SELECT U.username, B.*
 FROM sc_users AS U, sc_bookmarks AS B
 WHERE B.uId = U.uId AND B.bStatus = 0
 GROUP BY B.bModified DESC, B.bHash DESC
 ORDER BY B.bModified DESC
LIMIT 10
```

and you should create a combined index on status+modified+hash.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this today.

Comment: I will also implement this in SemanticScuttle itself, but that is a bit harder than it seems and will take some time.

Comment: cweiske, please see the update from jakub, which I also added to my original question.  Thanks,  -Eric